# use two sets of constants in one function

Tags: java, performance, function, constants

I have a function for which in two different situations I want to use two different sets of constants. Eg:in one i want to use

```
private final class MoveOverTarget
    {
        private final int SPEED = 3000;
        private final int SLOW_SPEED = 0;
        private final float D_B_SLOW_REGION = 0;
        public final float D_B_TARGET_RANGE = 0;
    }
```

and in another

```
private final class MoveTowardsTarget
    {
        private final int SPEED = 1000;
        private final int SLOW_SPEED = 500;
        private final float D_B_SLOW_REGION = 50;
        public final float D_B_TARGET_RANGE = 10;
    }
```

for the same function

```
private boolean bValInTargetRange(float targetValue, boolean moveOverTarget)
    {}
```

at the moment i can't think about an easy to implement solution and don't seem to find the correct keywords for google. Can you help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider using instances of a class to store related data (the set of constants), instead of separate classes?

Comment: If the values of the constants change, they are not constants :) Use a map, use two instances of the same class, with each instance initialized with the corresponding values, use enums or inheritance, etc. You have a lot of options here

Comment: @KarlKnechtel and fps thank you very much for these answers, I did it with two instances of a class which only stores the related data which i then use in my method.

Answer (score 1):

Make them `public static`:

```
public static final int SPEED = 3000;
```

And refer to them using the class name:

```
MoveOverTarget.SPEED
MoveTowardsTarget.SPEED
```

Also consider if using `enum`s would be better. Another option: define two copies of the method, one in each class, and refer to the constants from that class in the method.

Yet another option: define an abstract superclass, write the method there and access the constants with abstract methods. Then define two subclasses, and in each one implement the abstract methods that return different values for the constants, also defined in each of the subclasses.

Comment: Thank you. This seems overly complicated to me, and is about what I was looking to avoid.